# Bash or python scripting of iperf for different ip addresses

Tags: python, bash, iperf

How can I achieve the following using python or bash?

1. `iperf -s -B 234.5.6.7 -u -f m -i 1`

   - let the above command run for 5 seconds
   - kill the above process (e.g. `killall iperf`)
2. `iperf -s -B 234.5.6.8 -u -f m -i 1`

   - let the above command run for 5 seconds
   - kill the above process (eg `killall iperf`)
3. and so on...

Comment: you have not given any information, or attempt.  We are here to assist you.

Comment: Please provide more information so that we can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

`$!` in bash will give you the pid of the last background process. So you could do something quick and dirty like this in bash

```
#!/bin/bash 

iperf -s -B 234.5.6.7 -u -f m -I 1 &
FOO = $!
sleep 5
kill $FOO
iperf -s -B 234.5.6.8 -u -f m -I 1 &
FOO = $!
sleep 5
kill $FOO
```

Lather rinse repeat...

We can then refactor this to a for loop

```
#!/bin/bash

for IP in 234.5.6.7 234.5.6.8
do
  iperf -s -B $IP -u -f m -I 1 &
  FOO = $!
  sleep 5
  kill $FOO
done
```